# What distinction between Core Bluetooth State Preservation&Restoration and iBeacon?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, ibeacon

Core Bluetooth state preservation and restoration is built in to Core Bluetooth after iOS7, also support iBeacon. And what distinction between Core Bluetooth State Preservation&Restoration and iBeacon? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not applicable for iBeacons.  This is a CoreBluetooth feature and iBeacon tracking APIs are part of CoreLocation.

What's more, even if using CoreBluetooth for iBeacons (which you only do when transmitting as an iBeacon), you would not need this feature because the data transmitted are static -- there is no changing state.  Because the transmitted Bluetooth data do not change, state preservation and restoration provides no value for iBeacons.